# How do I override the default output of an object?

Tags: javascript, oop

Say in JavaScript I create a simple object:

```
function MyObj() {
    this.prop = "property";
}
```

Now if I create an instance of this and the output it to console I see the object representation:

```
var obj = new MyObj();
console.log(obj);
```

How can I instead make that output a string?:  For example, I would like that the console displays `My property value is 'property'` rather than [object object].

I've tried using `MyObj.prototype.toString`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could hook the browser console, and redefine it afterwards:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Joel",
    age: 32,
    toString: function() {
        return this.name + " is " + this.age + " years old.";
    }
};

var browserConsole = console;

console = {
    log: function(data) {
        if (typeof data === "object") {
            browserConsole.log(data.toString());
        } else {
            browserConsole.log(data);
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

`MyObj.prototype.toString() = function() {}`  will work, but won't output to the console. If you do something like

```
console.log("The object says: " + obj);
```

... you will see the output of `toString()`

```
function MyObj() {
    this.prop = "property";
}
MyObj.prototype.toString = function() {
   return "My property 'prop' has the value: '" + this.prop + "'";
}
var obj = new MyObj();
console.log("the object says: " + obj);

// the object says: My property 'prop' has the value: 'property'

// Or call toString() explicitly
console.log(obj.toString());
// My property 'prop' has the value: 'property'
```

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this without having an explicit string in the log call?

Comment: @shanethehat If you only want to dump it in the log, you can just call `obj.toString()`

Comment: I don't know how you could modify the behavior of the console to call `toString()` instead of dumping the object's contents.

Comment: This is actually an interview question, and I think it might be a deliberate red herring.  The requirement is that `console.log(obj);` would output a custom string, but if that's not possible that that's my answer.

Comment: @shanethehat I didn't say it isn't possible, I said I don't know how. By the way, for future interview or assignment questions, please make us aware of that before we start answering. We can usually guess if it is a direct homework assignment question, and take a somewhat different approach to assisting and answering. In your case though, you were already on the right track so I'm happy to help

Comment: Sorry, in my haste I forgot the tag! Added now.