# A Vector Class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vector

I'm trying to implement a vector object instantiated like below...

```js
var a = new Vector([1,2,3]);
var b = new Vector ([2,2,2]);
```

...and when I do a math operation I need something like this...

```js
a.add(b); // should return Vector([3,4,5])
```

...but my code below returns me just an array

```js
function Vector(components) {
  // TODO: Finish the Vector class.
  this.arr = components;
  this.add = add;
}

function add(aa) {
  if(this.arr.length === aa.arr.length) {
    var result=[];
    for(var i=0; i<this.arr.length; i++) {
       result.push(this.arr[i]+aa.arr[i]);
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return error;
  }
}
```

Please help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: Why not move to a functional approach to manipulate Vectors ? This meduim article explains the advantages very well.
https://hackernoon.com/more-functional-refactoring-a-vector-library-4bf3d6b88612

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap up your resulting array in a new `Vector` object:

```
function Vector(components) {
  // TODO: Finish the Vector class.
  this.arr = components;
  this.add = add;
}

function add(aa) {
  if(this.arr.length === aa.arr.length) {
    var result=[];
    for(var i=0; i<this.arr.length; i++) {
       result.push(this.arr[i]+aa.arr[i]);
    }
    return new Vector(result);
  } else {
    return error;
  }
}
```

I should note also that you may want to do further reading on creating JavaScript objects, in the area of creating methods (such as your `add` method) on the prototype of the `Vector` object.  There are many good tutorials out there.

Comment: thanx for the reply but that won't fix my problem. whrn i console.log(a.add(b)); it will return whole function code, hope this link will point you where i'm [link](http://jsbin.com/kobilalutu/1/edit?js,console )

Comment: It's logging the entire Vector object.  If you change it to log `b.add(a).arr` it will log just the array part of it.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that will give me just the result array but i want to return something like "Vector([3,4,5])"

Comment: You'll need to create a method that returns a string representation of your vector, and call that.  [This may be of use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943257/how-do-i-override-the-default-output-of-an-object), though I don't know how far you'll get with changing the `console.log` behaviour (as per the first answer) on jsbin...

Comment: thanx for the reference, it helped me understand my situation. Well i will try to implement something like that, hope will get what i need. ty!

Comment: `var Vector = function (components) {
  this.x = components;
};
Vector.prototype.add = function(b){
  var a = this.x
  b = b.x;
  if(a.length !== b.length) throw new TypeError("Vectors have different length");
  return new Vector(a.map(function(x,i){ return x + b[i]; }));
}` well above answer and this one are both are almost same but this will return Vector([3,4,5]); Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is simpler to extend javascript's native Array, so that there is no need for keeping around an extra `Vector.arr` property. Here is a simple implementation called for learning purposes that boils down to this, in modern JS:

```js
class Vector extends Array {
  // example methods
  add(other) {
    return this.map((e, i) => e + other[i]);
  }
}

// example usage
let v = new Vector(1, 2, 3);
console.log(v.add(v));
```

This class inherits Array's constructor. Note passing in a single value creates an empty Array of that length and not a length 1 Array. Vector would [require a `super` call in the constructor](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-constructor) to inherit [exotic Array behavior](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#array-exotic-object), such as having a special `length` property, but this shouldn't be needed for a math vector of fixed length.
You can include fancier constructor behavior here, such as being able to construct from an Array as input.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by James looks good but it's a bit old-fashioned in my opinion. Here is a way to solve the problem in modern ES6 Javascript Classes.

```
class Vector {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.arr = arr;
  }
  add(otherVector) {
    const oa = otherVector.arr;
    if (this.arr.length === oa.length) {
      let res = []
      for(let key in this.arr) {
        res[key] = this.arr[key] + oa[key]
      }
      return new Vector(res)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just use return this.arr.map( (o, index) =>  o + oa[index]), to replace you for loop logic (if you want more ES6 goodness)

Comment: and shouldn't the if statement throw an error instead of just not returning anything?