# How to pass rest parameters as input for a custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently trying to create a vectorSUM function in google scripts, which would sum up all vectors. I've looked into using the arguments method, but would much rather prefer using a rest parameter like the built in SUM function uses. I keep getting the error "missing formal parameter" this is my code. How would I go about using Optional parameters, as well as rest parameters in a custom function?

```
function vectorAdd(vector1, [vector2, ...]) {}
```

The built in SUM function uses

```
(value1, [value2, ...])
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785458/a-vector-class-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Vector Class in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785458/a-vector-class-in-javascript)

Comment: The native SUM function uses square brackets to indicate optional parameters.

Comment: The vector aspect I understand, I want to be able to pass as many optional inputs into my custom function using the same method as the SUM function