# Override print representation of a JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to take an array object and change its print representation - just of that object, not of all arrays in the program. I hoped setting the toString property would do the job, but it doesn't:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3]

// Prints using the default representation
console.log(a)

// Try to override toString
a.toString = function() {
  return 'some new representation'
}

// Still uses the default representation
console.log(a)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `console.log()` code does what it wants. Overriding `.toString()` will work when the array is coerced to a string value, but `console.log()` doesn't necessarily do that unless you force it to.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943257/how-do-i-override-the-default-output-of-an-object

Comment: Check the link  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307514/is-it-possible-to-override-javascripts-tostring-function-to-provide-meaningfu), you can see how to do that properrly ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];

// Prints using the default representation
console.log(a);

// Try to override toString
a.toString = function() {
  return 'some new representation'
}

// append blank string to invoke toString function
console.log(""+a);
```